# How can I submit multiple R job at once?

Tags: shell-script, cluster, r, qsub

I have a R-script which runs multiple files say file=1 to 50.
I usually submit repeated jobs say 5 times with 10 files each time by changing the number in R-script.
So, how can I submit the 5-job at once without submitting the job 5 times? In addition, I want to update the **default.out** and **errorfile** for each job.

sample bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=20,walltime=05:00:00

#PBS -m e
#PBS -o default.out
#PBS -e errorfile

module load R/4.0

Rscript ~/r_script1.R
```

Comment: Which implementation of qsub is on your cluster?  Torque?   SLURM?    Other?    I've got an answer partially written but the details depend on exactly what kind of cluster management software is being used.

Comment: @cas thank you for your reply. I used it in High-performance computing (HPC). I am not sure whether I have answered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify any or all of those options in the `qsub` command line, rather than as `#PBS ...` comments in the script.

e.g. your batch script could be re-written as:

```
qsub -l nodes=1:ppn=20,walltime=05:00:00 -m e -o default.out -e errorfile script.sh
```

With all of the options on the qsub command line, `script.sh` only needs to contain:

```
#!/bin/bash

module load R/4.0
Rscript ~/r_script1.R
```

You can mix both methods of providing options to qsub.  e.g.  you could provide the `-o` and `-e` options on the command line, with the remainder in the script as `#PBS` comments:

```
$ qsub -o default.out -e errorfile script2.sh
```

script2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=20,walltime=05:00:00
#PBS -m e

module load R/4.0

Rscript ~/r_script1.R
```

You can then combine that with a bash `for` loop:

```
for i in {1..5} ; do
  qsub -o "default.$i.out" -e "errorfile.$i" script2.sh
done
```

If you need to pass the value of the loop variable `$i` to the script, that's possible - but there are several different ways of doing it, depending on which cluster management software you're using (e.g. slurm or torque or something else).   One of the simplest, and likely to be available no matter which version of `qsub` you're using is to use qsub's `-v` option.

e.g. if you needed to run a different R script in each job, r_script1.R, r_script2.R, etc you could use `-v i` to have `$i` available in the environment of the script:

```
for i in {1..5} ; do
  qsub -o "default.$i.out" -e "errorfile.$i" -v i script3.sh
done
```

script3.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=20,walltime=05:00:00
#PBS -m e

module load R/4.0

Rscript ~/r_script"$i".R
```

Some implementations of qsub allow passing arguments to the script directly on the command line, which you can then use as normal positional parameters ($1, $2, $3, etc) within the script.

Most (all?) implementations of `qsub` also support the `-t` option for specifying a job array.  This can be accessed in the job script with the PBS_ARRAYID environment variable.  e.g.

```
qsub script4.sh
```

script4.sh (this uses shell redirection for output and error files rather than qsub's `-o` and `-e` options):

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=20,walltime=05:00:00
#PBS -m e
#PBS -t 1-5

module load R/4.0

Rscript ~/r_script"$PBS_ARRAYID".R > "default.$PBS_ARRAYID.out" 2> "errorfile.$PBS_ARRAYID"
```

BTW, PBS_ARRAYID is an exported environment variable, so can be accessed within the R script with `Sys.getenv("PBS_ARRAYID")` if required.  You can use this to, for example, construct input and output filenames and for if/then/else decisions to control what the R script does.  This would be better than having multiple slightly-different versions of the same R script.

NOTE: While I used to administer HPC clusters running both torque and slurm, it has been about 8 years since I did so.  All of the above examples are written from memory (and searching for `qsub` man pages on the internet), and have not been tested on an actual cluster.  They may (probably will) need some changes to work, especially the last example using $PBS_ARRAYID - they're offered as rough examples of how you can do what you want.

Comment: Hi, @cas I tried script3.sh. This could not read R files. So, the error is Rscript ~/r_script"$i".R. However, the last suggestion seems a good approach but with my limited knowledge I will exhume further.

Comment: @b_takhel maybe try `export i` immediately before the `for` loop.