# Bash script for reading multiple files

Tags: shell-script, parallelism, r, qsub

I have multiple R scripts to read (up to 3 i.e. tr1.R, tr2.R, tr3.R).
The bash script for reading a single script is given below

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=10,walltime=00:05:00
#PBS -M 
#PBS -m e
module load R/4.0
Rscript ~/tr1.R
```

I tried the following as suggested by [@cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650937/how-can-i-submit-multiple-r-job-at-once)

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=10,walltime=00:05:00
#PBS -M 
#PBS -m e
module load R/4.0
**Rscript ~/tr"$i".R**
```

Further, the job is submitted using

```
for i in {1..3} ; do
  qsub -o "default.$i.out" -e "errorfile$i" -v i script.sh
done
```

This couldnot read **Rscript ~/tr"$i".R**.

Answer (score 0):

This is quick and dirty:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Printing script.......\n"

y=0
for (( y=0; y <= 9; y++ ))
do
   echo "file tr$y.R contents: "
   cat tr$y.R
   echo ""   
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How about solving that in R like this,

combined.R:

```
source (tr1.R)
source (tr2.R)
source (tr3.R)
```

or like this.

combined.R:

```
for (i in c(1:9)) {
    filename <- paste ("tr", i, ".R", sep="")
    if (file.exists (filename)) {
        source (filename)
    }
}
```

And then you can load `combined.R`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=10,walltime=00:05:00
#PBS -M 
#PBS -m e
module load R/4.0
Rscript ~/combined.R
```

---

Oh, I see now that you want to run jobs in paralell. The solution I posted does not run jobs in paralell, but I will leave the answer here. Maybe somebody will find it useful. Maybe you can apply something like this https://www.blasbenito.com/post/02_parallelizing_loops_with_r/ or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318139/run-a-for-loop-in-parallel-in-r.